# JPA entitymanager run native sql query to get everything out from a table

Tags: sql, database, jpa, entitymanager, hibernate-criteria

What I need to do is to run a piece of native sql query to select everything and get 
data out from a specific table.

My app is a spring hibernate based web app. Here is my code:

DAOserviceImpl:

```
@Service
public class ItemServiceImpl implements ItemService {

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

    @Transactional
    public void addItem(Item item) {
        em.persist(item);
    }

    @Transactional
    public List<Item> iosADVsearchResults(String itemCode) {
        //run native query with jpa
        List<Item> itemList = (List<Item>)em.createQuery("SELECT * FROM item itemcode='" + itemCode + "'")
            .getResultList(); 
        return itemList;
    }
}
```

but what I eventually get is this error:

> HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: = near line 1, column 35 [SELECT itemcode FROM item itemcode='ll3369']

I was following this tutorial: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/vasiliev-jpql-087123.html

Please help, any code example would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

If You are using JPA your query to get all records should be like this:

```
List<Item> itemList = (List<Item>) em.createQuery("SELECT i FROM item where  itemcode=?1)
                                    .setParameter(1, itemcode)
                                    .getResultList();
```

this will return all the record which matches the parameter itemcode ..

Answer (score 1):

`em.createQuery()` expects a query written in JPQL, not SQL (see [this](http://java-persistence-performance.blogspot.com/2012/05/jpql-vs-sql-have-both-with-eclipselink.html) for some info). For SQL query, use `em.createNativeQuery()`

```
List<Item> itemList = (List<Item>)em.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM item WHERE itemcode='" + itemCode + "'", Item.class).getResultList();
```